# Finding the inverse function, is there a technique?

Tags: functions, inverse

I came across a way to find whether some number is inside a sequence of numbers.
For example the sequence (simple function for positive odd numbers):
$$a(n) = 2n + 1.$$
So the numbers inside it go: $1, 3, 5, 7, \ldots$

If I want to test if the sequence contains a number $N,$ I reverse the formula to this: $$n = (N - 1) / 2.$$
If $n$ is an integer, then we know that $N$ is inside the sequence.

> But, here is my question, how can I find the inverse function of this formula:
>   $$a(n) = n(2n - 1)$$

---

Note: Please do comment every step and explain the logic behind it, so I'll understand

Comment: You could "solve for $n$" by completing the square.

Comment: Thank you for commenting, I have edited my post to match my needs. What do you mean by 'completing the square'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note: there is some fine print about domains and well-defined inverses, but I'll skip to the computations)

Completing the square is a method for isolating a variable in a quadratic equation. For example, if we were trying to solve $$x^2 + 4x = 5$$ we could add $4$ to both sides to get $$x^2 + 4x + 4 = 9$$ and then recognize the left hand side as a *perfect square trinomial*. 
So we could write $$(x+2)^2 = 9$$ and take square roots to get $$x + 2 = \pm 3 \Rightarrow x = -2 \pm 3$$

This gives us TWO values, so we won't have a "well-defined" function unless we restrict the domain.

In your case, you have $a = 2n^2 - n$, or $a/2 = n^2 - n/2$, and we'll add $\dfrac{1}{16}$ to both sides to get $$\dfrac{a}{2} + \dfrac{1}{16} = (n - \dfrac{1}{4})^2$$

Now take the square root and add $\dfrac{1}{16}$ to get $n$. *(Insert comment on domain restrictions here)*

Comment: Thanks so much! That was exactly the solution I was looking for, very useful in general for other needs.

Comment: Like I said, there are some details that you'll need to mind, depending on the sequence. You were able to "reverse engineer" the positive integer sequence because addition and multiplication are invertible (one-to-one). Some functions [are not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Example:_squaring_and_square_root_functions)

Answer (score 0):

So what you're describing a situation where any element of the sequence is defined as:$$ a_n = p(n), $$ where $p(n) \in \Bbb Z[n],$ i.e. a polynomial in $n$ with integer coefficients. Now to test that a particular integer $N$ is in the sequence it suffices to show that there exists some integer $n$ such that $p(n) - N = 0.$ This is equivalent to saying that the polynomial $p(n) - N$ has an integer roots.

This test for integer roots can be done by [the rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem). Equivalently, you can find the roots for the polynomial equation $p(n) - N = 0,$ e.g. by factoring, and then check whether any of the roots is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is your test value then $a = n(2n-1)$ is a quadratic in $n$ with the solution

$$n = \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt{8a+1}}{4}$$

and you will want this to be a positive integer if your test value is positive.